# a print statement casting to list destroys the list?

Tags: python

Could anyone explain this:

let dict_list be:

```
dict_list = [
{'a':1, 'b':3},
{'a':2, 'b':4}
]
```

### Case A (the list is destroyed)

Then the following code:

```
1 print('length: ' + str(len(dict_list)))
2 filtered_dict_list = filter(lambda d: d['a'] == 1, dict_list)
3 print('length: ' + str(len(list(filtered_dict_list))))
4 dict_list = list(filtered_dict_list)
5 print('length: ' + str(len(dict_list)))
```

Will print:

```
length: 2
length: 1
length: 0
```

dict_list is gone forever in the code

### Case B (the list is not destroyed)

By switching line 3 and 4:

```
1 print('length: ' + str(len(dict_list)))
2 filtered_dict_list = filter(lambda d: d['a'] == 1, dict_list)
3 dict_list = list(filtered_dict_list)
4 print('length: ' + str(len(list(filtered_dict_list))))
5 print('length: ' + str(len(dict_list)))
```

We get:

```
length: 2
length: 0
length: 1
```

And can keep on working with our filtered dict_list

Comment: `filtered_dict_list` isn't a list in Python 3. It's a `filter` object, which is lazily evaluated and becomes exhausted once consumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, `filter()` returns a `filter` object, which is a lazy generator and does not automatically produce a `list` object like Python 2's `filter()` does. In your code, you are simply changing which result is printed first.

```
1 print('length: ' + str(len(dict_list)))
2 filtered_dict_list = filter(lambda d: d['a'] == 1, dict_list)
3 print('length: ' + str(len(list(filtered_dict_list)))) # consumes filtered_dict_list
4 dict_list = list(filtered_dict_list) # attempts to consume an exhausted generator, saving an empty list
5 print('length: ' + str(len(dict_list))) # length of that empty list
```

In the second block:

```
1 print('length: ' + str(len(dict_list)))
2 filtered_dict_list = filter(lambda d: d['a'] == 1, dict_list)
3 dict_list = list(filtered_dict_list) # consume filtered_dict_list, and *save* it
4 print('length: ' + str(len(list(filtered_dict_list)))) # attempts to consume an exhausted generator, result is empty
5 print('length: ' + str(len(dict_list))) # print the *saved* dict_list
```

And it's not the `print()` call that exhausts the generator; it's the `list()` call. If you sent `filtered_dict_list` to `print()` without first sending it to `list()`, it would print something like `<filter object at 0x0000000003E32470>`.

Comment: Thank you, that explained it really well! :)